# How does WordPress decide what template to use as frontpage

Tags: theme-development, templates, options, frontpage

I'm so confused about this thing. I tried to figure this out for ours, but can't seem to find a solution. I'm currently working on a theme for a client, using the [components business starter theme](http://components.underscores.me/). I'm new to theme creation and still didn't quite get the hang of everything. Here is what I want to do:

Most of the time, you don't want to use the default homepage as the frontpage, but define a static page "Home". So I created a static page and went to Settings->Reading, to define my "Home" page as front page.

In any theme I know, including the standard WordPress themes and many themes I used so far, this will make the "Home" page be the front page.

However, in the theme I startet with, my frontpage stays empty. I don't get any content from my "Home" page there. This is a very basic starter theme, but I think this should be included right? It's a basic function from the WP backend.

I'm trying to get my theme to display the page that is set under "Front page" in the WordPress settings, but I just don't know how. When I change the theme to "twnetyfourteen", the page.php template is triggered instead of the index.php, when I view the homepage. In my theme however, it's still the index.php. How does WordPress decide, which one of both to chose?

Answer (score 4):

Front page template logic is horrendous legacy mess. While back I wrote a very thorough [front page cheatsheet](https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/front-page-logic/), I *still* can't completely remember how it works.

You are right to notice that theme in your case doesn't behave in same way as other themes *typically* do.

If you run down specific template being used (plugin like Query Monitor can help with this) it's [`front-page.php`, here it is in their github repo](https://github.com/Automattic/theme-components/blob/master/types/business/front-page.php) (and it seems to be moved in theme root, that's what generator thing does).

It is *very* uncommon for this file to ship in a public theme because it will *always override any other front page template*.

In this specific case it is being used to implement that "business" configuration of the theme, displaying hero image and testimonials (look at its source). It chooses *not* to output page content for that case, that's why it doesn't appear.

So in a nutshell it is niche theme, built for a specific purpose, in a way that public themes typically aren't.